# set maximum number of grid rows in jqWidgets

Tags: jqwidget

Is that possible to set `maximum number visible rows` in `$('#gridId').jqxGrid({})`? Currently the method is like below

```
    `$('#gridId').jqxGrid({
        source: dataAdapter,
        autoheight: true,
        keyboardnavigation: false,
        showfilterrow: true,
        filterable: true,
        sortable: true,
        //max number of row
     });`
```

I am using jQWidgets v2.8.2.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the Paging feature and set the "pagesize" property. Example: [jQWidgets Grid Paging](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/initialpage.htm?arctic)